# Могу ли я просто скопировать модуль для python из старой папки в новую?

Tags: python, requests

Я установил python на новый сервер и мне нужно обойти установление модуля requests. Он есть на другой машине. Можно ли просто скопировать файлы манульно? Будет ли все работать правильно или это не лучшая практика?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pip freeze

По-моему, самое лучшее для новичка и лентяя - это делать `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, получим список установленных модулей с их версиями. После этого на новой машине делаем `pip install -r requirements.txt`, и подгружаем нужные нам модули с точно такими же версиями.

### Virtualenv

Так же рекомендуется использовать `virtualenv` — это инструмент, позволяющий создавать виртуальные окружения с пакетами. Можно рассмотреть ее как своего рода "песочницу".  Разные "песочницы" имеют разный набор пакетов разных версий. Плюс к этому уходит проблема засорения системы ненужными пакетами, так как "песочницы" можно легко создавать и удалять. В песочницу устанавливаются пакеты, которые необходимы для конкретной реализации. Используя два `virtualenv` на проект — одного чистого, содержащего минимальный набор зависимостей, и одного, предназначенного для разработки. Думаю, такой подход в любом случае не лишен смысла, так как вряд ли вы захотите тянуть на боевой сервер всевозможные моки и фреймворки для тестирования.

[Статья](https://djbook.ru/examples/85/) о том как использовать `virtualenv`.

### Python way

Чтобы объявить необходимые зависимости для своего пакета, можно указать их в `install_requires` в `setup.py`. И вообще написание для своего проекта `setup.py` - это лучшая практика, о чем написано в [этой документации](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/).

Answer (score 1):

Если версии питона (и возможно, разрядность ОСИ) совпадают и Вы все скопируете правильно, то должно работать. Но не нужно забывать о такой штуке как зависимости. Их тоже нужно будет разрешить.

В целом, лучше просто поставить все нужные Вам модули с помощью пакетного менеджера или обычным pip. Иначе в будущем Вы можете оказаться в ситуации, когда какой то пакет будет ставить зависимости и захочет поставить request (или просто обновить его или его зависимости) и все развалится.